# Generate .txt files from pdf files keeping the name same as in pdf using python

Tags: python, loops, ocr, file-handling, file-generation

I have a directory containing pdf files. I have written the code that performs OCR when you pass a filename to an object of the wand.image class. What I want to do presently is to loop over the directory of pdf files and generate a OCR'd txt file for each pdf and save it some directory. The code that I have written till now is as follows:

```
import io
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
from wand.image import Image as wi




pdf = wi(filename = r"D:\files\aba7d525-04b8-4474-a40d-e94f9656ed42.pdf", resolution = 300)

pdfImg = pdf.convert('jpeg')

imgBlobs = []

for img in pdfImg.sequence:
    page = wi(image = img)
    imgBlobs.append(page.make_blob('jpeg'))

extracted_text = []

for imgBlob in imgBlobs:
    im = Image.open(io.BytesIO(imgBlob))
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(im, lang = 'eng')
    extracted_text.append(text)

print(extracted_text[0])
```

The thing is if you see my code, ("pdf = .."), I have hardcoded a filename in my code but I need to pass a directory there so that all the files in that directory can be OCR'd and also I need to take as output all those files with their filenames with just .pdf being replaced by .txt. How can I do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use glob

Example:

```
import os
import glob
from wand.image import Image as wi

files = glob.glob("D:\files\*")

for file in files:
    pdf = wi(filename = file, resolution = 300)
    # write your code
    with open("D:\extracted_files\" + os.path.split(file)[-1].split(".")[0] + ".txt", 'w') as f:
        f.write(extracted_text)
```

Comment: Thanks but how do I get the exact filenames as output. A sample file in the directory looks like this : "000dbf9d-d53f-465f-a7ce-722722136fb7465.pdf". I need output as  "000dbf9d-d53f-465f-a7ce-722722136fb7465.txt" and this should take place for all files in the directory. I think I need to split the filenames and then join maybe, any idea?

Comment: Also, it's just creating one file and overwriting on it and not saving individual new .txt files

Comment: os.path.split(file) will give you a list of directories and file, os.path.split(file)[-1] will pick the file name, os.path.split(file)[-1].split(".") will split the file name on period("."), os.path.split(file)[-1].split(".")[0] will give the file name without extension, os.path.split(file)[-1].split(".")[0] + ".txt" will add the pdf file name and .txt extension